# How do I toggle between v-textfield and v-autocomplete in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-directives

I am using column count in the grid to generate dynamic text fields at runtime. In the code below Object.keys(entryData) will have the list of columns. When i get the item.field condition as 'councilDisplay', I want that particular textfield to be autocomplete rest others should remain text-fields only. I am planning to load the data into autocomplete for saving purpose but at this point the condition is either giving all textfields or all autocomplete. Do I need to write the condition in the v-text-field tag? This is the problem I am having.
I want to do only Council Display as auto complete.

[image]

```
<v-layout align-center
            v-for="(item, i) in Object.keys(entryData)"
            :key ="i"
            v-if="item.field != ''">
            <template v-if="item.field != 'councilDisplay'">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="entryData[item]"
              :label="getLabel(item)"
              :disabled="setDisable(item)"
              v-if="msgTitle != 'Do You Want To Delete Record?'">
            </v-text-field>
            </template>
            <template v-else>
              <v-autocomplete
                v-model="entryData[item]"
                :label="getLabel(item)"
                :disabled="setDisable(item)">
              </v-autocomplete>
            </template>
</v-layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cause, but I see that you have unnecessary `<template>` tags. That tag is available for toggling mutliple tags at once, which doesn't seem to be needed.

you can just use the `v-autocomplete` and `v-text-field`

```
      <v-layout align-center
        v-for="(item, i) in Object.keys(entryData)"
        :key ="i"
        v-if="item.field != '' && msgTitle != 'Do You Want To Delete Record?'">

        <v-text-field
          v-if="item.field != 'councilDisplay'"
          v-model="entryData[item]"
          :label="getLabel(item)"
          :disabled="setDisable(item)"
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-autocomplete
          v-else
          v-model="entryData[item]"
          :label="getLabel(item)"
          :disabled="setDisable(item)"
        ></v-autocomplete>
      </v-layout>
```

Comment: Yes you are right but I ma facing the same issue I think I need to work on v-if condition.

Comment: @NikulVyas uses [dynamic component](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#is) may be one option.